# ExpandableListView expand only on a specific Button?

Tags: android, listview, button, expandablelistview, expand

well i´m trying to create a ExpandableListView like Spotify it does... But i don´t have any idea how do disable the LinearLayout to act like a button (Expand the list) I have created a image which should describe what i like. I like to have the possibility to handle a click on the text / image (parent) as a normal interaction. A click on the right button should expand the list like in Spotify...

[image: First picture show the expand action (now), second show the expand action how it should be...]

Comment: If you handle onGroupClick and return true then the group doesn't expand.If you return false and group has > 0 children then the group expands.

Comment: So do you think i should implement the ClickListener-interface and just return true and register the Button on another ClickListener and expand the group manually? Is there no official way to specify a button as the expand ressource?

Comment: Well right now i´m able to detect a click on the group and a click on the imagebutton on the right. But i set the imagebutton in the adapter to onClickListener which only get the view as parameter... So how do i know which group i should expand or collapse?

Comment: please give your code, I was asking you to implement OnChildClickListener, OnGroupClickListener of expandable list in the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the onCreate from the ChannelList which extends ListFragment. It stores the data and generate a new Adapter if the Fragment is called.

```
@Override   
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{                               
    m_ListView = new ExpandableListView(getActivity());
    m_ListView.setId(android.R.id.list);

    m_ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    m_ListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(m_MultiChoiceModeListener);

    m_ChannelListAdapter = new ChannelListAdapter(getActivity(), this);
    m_ListView.setAdapter(m_ChannelListAdapter);
    m_ListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
    m_ListView.setOnGroupClickListener(this);

    return m_ListView;
}
```

On the Adapter i have the getGroupView Method which look like:

```
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) 
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_channelwithimage, viewGroup, false);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelwithimage);
    textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());

    ImageButton imbu = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    //imbu.setOnClickListener(this);    
    imbu.setFocusable(false);

    return view;
}
```

So if i register the ImageButton in the adapter it will call the onClick from the adapter. But in the onClick i do not know which group was clicked... If i do not register the button on any listener it will not call the onGroupClick from the ChannelList...

Answer (score 21):

This is a bit old question, but this answer might help someone.

If you want to expand/collapse group by clicking on specific `Button` or some other `View`, you have to get that Button in `getGroupView` method in your Adapter class. Then, in `onClick` method of your `Button` you have, either to cast `parent` to `ExpandableListView`, or to pass List's reference in constructor when you create adapter.

I prefer the first approach. Here's the code, assuming that you have one `TextView` and an `ImageView` that is the arrow. I've added changing the arrow state too.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.left_drawer_list_group, parent, false);
    }

    TextView listHeaderText = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.left_menu_list_header_text);
    ImageView listHeaderArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.left_menu_list_header_arrow);

    listHeaderText.setText(headerTitle);

    //Set the arrow programatically, so we can control it
    int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float : android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float;
    listHeaderArrow.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

    listHeaderArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isExpanded) ((ExpandableListView) parent).collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            else ((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition, true);

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Additionally, you would like to disable expanding/collapsing in `onGroupClick` listener.

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {

    //Do some other stuff, but you shall not expand or collapse

    return true;
}
```

There is another method, but the fairly bad one, and that is that you copy entire `Adapter` class inside the class where you create `ExpandableListView` and set `Adapter`. But do not do that. 
Seriously! ;)

Comment: its expanding but not collapsing

Answer (score 0):

Not overly elegant solution but it helped me out:

I've preserved the original groupIndicator. I liked the behavior as it was.

On the groupItem layout I simply blocked the space with empty view so that the original groupIndicator was still clickable:

```
<LinearLayout> 
....

<!--just dummy space underneath the default expand_collapse group icon - this way original expand collapse behavior is preserved on the icon-->
<View
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</View>

<!-- text view will have actionListener -->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        .... /> 
.... 
</LinearLayout>
```

Than sneaked in callBack object while creating ExpandableListAdapter and hooked it onClick on the "category_name" (for both child and group elements)

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
public interface OnCategoryActionListener {
    boolean onCategorySelected(long categoryId);
}
....

public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, Category rootCategory,    
OnCategoryActionListener callBack) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rootCategory = rootCategory;     
    this.callBack = callBack;
}
....
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View 
convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String categoryName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   
          context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(categoryName);
    item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            callBack.onCategorySelected(getGroupId(groupPosition));
        }
    });
  .....
```

All you have to do now is to initialize properly ExpandableListAdapter in master fragment class

```
expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), this.rootCategory,     
    new OnCategoryActionListener());
expListView = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.categories_list);
expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```